# How do you create an array of objects using a javascript loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, loops

Hi I have an application that I have got half working. I have an array of objects, each with their properties already set and can call them like this `myarray[i].property`. I have an if statment that searchs through the array, within a loop, and pulls out any where `myarray[i].property == my var`.

The issue I'm having is that I want to put these results into a new array, built by the if statment/loop combo that searchs the first array, and I can't make it work.

This is what I have tried, but failed with?

```
var c = 0;
var matches = new Array('application', 'sclass', 'type', 'motor', 'bearings', 'gears', 'modelno', 'name', 'speed', 'v3_3', 'v4_8', 'v6_0', 'v7_2', 'weight', 'diensions', 'opvoltage', 'image', 'description');

//loop through servos array and pull any servo that has a matching application value to that selected by the search filter
for(var i=0; i < servos.length; i++){
    if servos[i].application == document.searchFilters.applicationMenu.value) {
        //populate the new 'matches' array with the details from the servos pulled from the inital arary
        matches[c] = new servo(servos[i].application, servos[i].sclass, servos[i].type, servos[i].motor, servos[i].bearings, servos[i].gears, servos[i].modelno, servos[i].name, servos[i].speed, servos[i].v3_3, servos[i].v4_8, servos[i].v6_0, servos[i].v7_2, servos[i].weight, servos[i].dimensions, servos[i].opvoltage, servos[i].image, servos[i].description);
        c++;
        } else if (document.searchFilters.applicationMenu.value == 0){
        //sets the value of servoDtore locally
        var servoStore = 0;}
```

Further in the code I have the line `document.getElementById('servoDisplay').innerHTML = "search result " + matches[c].modelno; //display servos model numbers stored within the matches array`

Where am I going wrong, why do I always get '.modelno is null or undefined' errors whenever I try to call matches[c].modelno?

Comment: I assume `mew` is actually `new`?

Comment: yup just a typo as I didn't copy and paste code over, as its on a different pc to this one

Comment: Do you ever reset the value of c...?

Comment: I don't think I do, but at the same time, when testing I've added an alert to display 'matches[c].modelno' just after, and even before I increment c and it still says undefined.

Its really bugging me as I can't work out what I've got wrong with it :(

Answer (score 1):

Let me try. Please tell me if I understood you incorrectly. I have modifyed your JS code to the following:

```
var matches = ['application', 'sclass', 'type', 'motor',
               'bearings', 'gears', 'modelno', 'name', 'speed',
               'v3_3', 'v4_8', 'v6_0', 'v7_2', 'weight',
               'dimensions', 'opvoltage', 'image', 'description'],
    output = [],
    modelnos = [];
    // c variable is unnecessary now

// Loop through servos array and pull any servo that has a matching application value to that selected by the search filter
for(var i = 0, len = servos.length; i < len; i+= 1) {
    if (document.searchFilters.applicationMenu.value === servos[i].application) {
        // Populate the new 'matches' array with the details from the servos pulled from the inital arary
        var newEntry = new servo(servos[i].application, servos[i].sclass, servos[i].type, servos[i].motor,
                                 servos[i].bearings, servos[i].gears, servos[i].modelno, servos[i].name, servos[i].speed,
                                 servos[i].v3_3, servos[i].v4_8, servos[i].v6_0, servos[i].v7_2, servos[i].weight,
                                 servos[i].dimensions, servos[i].opvoltage, servos[i].image, servos[i].description);

        output.push(newEntry);
        modelnos.push(newEntry.modelno);
        // c++;
    } else if (document.searchFilters.applicationMenu.value === 0) {
        var servoStore = 0;
    }
}

// Display servos model numbers stored within the matches array
document.getElementById('servoDisplay').innerHTML = "Search result: " + modelnos.join('<br />');
```

Comment: Thats close to what I'm wanting cheers Lappie. I was hoping to store each property that newEntry has within one array like "appRes" because the next stage of my project is to search through the "appRes" array and repeat the process, this time putting any matches into a new array called "classRes"

The app I'm trying to create is a search filter, I have 6 boxes to filter the search by. So I want if statement1 = condition1 then build array with results, then search that array for condtion2 and build new array with those results repeating for a total of 6 times